# How to convert PDF file to XML

Tags: c#, xml, pdf

Can any body tell me how to convert pdf file to xml file.
I want to store resume in xml file, i.e. if any user upload the resume in pdf file then it will convert in xml file and in xml file only store some basic detail like name, address, education detail, etc.

please give me answer

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287880/pdf-to-xml-conversion-using-net

Comment: Duplicate, as already commented by @RobertLangdon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to read the PDF file using [itextsharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

after that filter your required information and then create a xml file using [XML](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/create-xml-in-C-Sharp/)