# using leadtools to convert pdf to xml using c#.net

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, leadtools-sdk

I am working on a project to use leadtools to convert pdf to xml,i could find almost all conversions except to xml file.please suggest a sample program if possible,its an emergency requirement.

Comment: Some versions and some features of LEADTOOLS support saving or converting to XML. Which version of LEADTOOLS are you using (18, 19, etc.)? Also, which classes of the toolkit are you employing (OCR, Leadtools.Forms.DocumentWriters.DocumentWriter, Leadtools.Documents.Converters.DocumentConverter , ...)? For example, the IOcrDocument.SaveXml() method only exists with the recent versions of the SDK.
If you're using OCR, which engine (Professional, Advantage or Plus)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to convert pdf to xml in c#..

It is very easy with XMLExtractor

Here are some links..you can find these:
https://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfextractorsdk/convert-pdf-to-xml

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/10576/convert-pdf-document-to-xml-using-csharpnet

[pdf to xml conversion using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287880/pdf-to-xml-conversion-using-net)

and another solution is that, when you convert pdf in your code at that time you can convert it in xml..using itextsharp