# Itext7 .net replace text by other text

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I'm searching for a way to replace text in a PDF with other by using itext7.
I get lost in some PDF terms and classes.

I find a very simple example by itext authors, but it won't fit my needs, as my PDF are far more complex (actually are a newspaper).

My idea is to search for a specific text in the page and replace part of the text by others. It has to be in the same position.

One thing that I don't understood is this a complex task, but acrobat pro can edit the text boxes so easily. Why I cannot find a text object and change its value as acrobat does?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by converting the PDF to XML, making my changes the XML, then changing it back to a PDF. Seems easier than trying to manipulate the PDF directly. Maybe start here:

[pdf to xml conversion using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287880/pdf-to-xml-conversion-using-net)

Comment: I think this will break the layout and make my pdf a mess